# socket.io is not showing console.log message when connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to console.log a message whenever someone connects to my server. Please advise what I did wrong or how to improve my code.

**server.js**

```
// express server setup
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const port = process.env.PORT || 1991

// middleware
app.use(cors())

//api
const metrics = require('./routes/api/metrics')
app.use('/api/metrics', metrics)

// 
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server running @ port ${port}`);
})

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('socket.io connected')
})
```

Comment: move server.listen to the bottom :/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone no, it is still not working after moving it to the bottom

Comment: show the client-side code, how do you know people are connecting?

Comment: Can you confirm the initial `console.log()` call is functioning that reports the server is running?

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler yes the first console.log is running but not the second one